# How can I run "Video for everybody" in current ubuntu (i.e. without specially compiling the latest ffmpeg)?

Tags: command-line, video, webserver, ffmpeg, mencoder

I first asked "How do I convert a video to all formats neccesary for [Video For Everybody](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody)" [on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/424015/what-bunch-of-ffmpeg-scripts-do-i-need-to-run-video-for-everybody).  The answer involved compiling the latest ffmpeg.

Later, I asked "How do I strip the metadata from a quicktime file" [here on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139570/how-do-i-remove-all-metadata-from-a-quicktime-movie-file).  The answer to *that* doesn't work for me, because now I've got the latest ffmpeg compiled in my Ubuntu.

So how do I convert to all the formats necessary using Ubuntu's old ffmpeg (or mencoder or some other CLI answer)?

Answer (score 0):

See [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/230155/112879) to the metadata question; to remove metadata with an up-to-date ffmpeg, you can simply:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map 0 -map_metadata -1 -c copy output.mp4
```

---

As for your actual question: the avconv in the Ubuntu repositories can output H.264, AAC (albeit it doesn't have libfdk_aac, so you'll have to rely on the lacklustre internal ffmpeg AAC encoder), theora video and vorbis audio. I don't know if it supports VP8 video, but *if it does* then the commands listed in that SU question should work perfectly well.